# jQuery using 'this' in an if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, this

I'm using an `if` statement in order to determine if an element has any children. If it does NOT have any children, I want to do something to that element only.

Here's the premise of what I'm trying to do:

```
if ($("#div a").children().length > 0){
    $(this).hide();
}
```

So if an `<a>` tag has no children, I want to do something to that specific element (or multiple elements that also have no children).

The problem is that `this` hasn't been defined because it's an `if` statement.

I could be completely missing something but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** Added [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/bxDNq/4/) Link

You can use `.filter` to check the condition and call `.hide` on the filter results. See below,

```
$("#div a").filter(function () {
  return ($(this).children().length > 0)
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 9):

you could use each to iterate through elements

```
$('input').each(function(){
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this).addClass('has-value');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution is to place the element in a variable.

```
var elem = $("#div a");
if (elem.children().length > 0){
    elem.hide();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if your answer would really work if #div has multiple `a` tags. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/bxDNq/5/