# Using $(this) in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We need to let the user enter a number in an `<input type='number'>` and, if it's negative, the `negative` style will apply, which will make the displayed text red.  However, I am having trouble getting the `if` statement to work.

HTML:

```
<span class="input">
    <input type="text" value="-">
    <input type="number" class="hidden">
</span><br>
<span class="input">
    <input type="text" value="-">
    <input type="number" class="hidden">
</span>
```

`$(this).prev().addClass('negative');` doesn't work in the `if` statement in the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input [type="text"]').on('focus', function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass().focus();
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
    $('.input [type="number"]').on('blur', function(){
        var number = Math.round($(this).val() * 100) / 100;
        var text = number.toFixed().toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        if (number < 0) {
            $(this).prev().addClass('negative');
            text = "("+text.replace(/-/g,"")+")";
        }
        if (!number) {text = "-";}
        $(this).prev().val(text);
        $(this).prev().removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/00pxe49t/2/). It will work if you take it out of the `if` statement, so the issue seems to be that `$(this)` is not making its way into the `if` statement. (**Edit**: Seems my assumption about this was incorrect. See the comments below.) [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002256/jquery-using-this-in-an-if-statement) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192166/if-statement-syntax-using-this-in-jquery) similar questions made use of `.filter` to resolve this issue, but I couldn't figure out how to make that work with the code above.

So how do I get this to work?

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere, the use of `$(this)` inside the if statement is correct. What is your fiddle supposed to do? Every time I click on the yellow input it just disappears

Comment: if statement blocks do not have a different scope so `$(this)` _"not making its way into the if"_ is not true

Comment: Now I'm truly at a loss. The `.replace()` function is working within the `if` statement, and `$(this).prev().addClass('negative');` works when outside of the `if` statement, so I thought I had narrowed down what was causing the issue.

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/00pxe49t/8/ what you want?

Comment: `removeClass()` is your problem without an argument it removes all classes, so your line `$(this).prev().removeClass();` is removing your `negative` class after you have added it

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks, that fixed it... and that mistake merits a total facepalm.

Comment: @Huangism Not quite. The `number` field should only be visible when focus is on that particular `text`/`number` pair.  Otherwise, the `text` field is visible. Based on the other input here, this is now working in Chrome but not yet in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the scope of `$this` or even the `if`. The problem is that you are adding class `negative` to the textbox with `$(this).prev().addClass('negative');` and about 5 lines later removing it again when you do `$(this).prev().removeClass();`

You need to specify that you only want to remove class `hidden` and that bit works fine.

After that you also need to handle if they change from negative to positive, so add another block to remove the `negative` class.

Lastly it is probably safer to check `if(!number)` first and do the other paths after.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input [type="text"]').on('focus', function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass().focus();
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
    $('.input [type="number"]').on('blur', function(){
        var number = Math.round($(this).val() * 100) / 100;
        var text = number.toFixed().toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
        if (!number) {
            text = "-";
            $(this).prev().removeClass('negative');
        }
        else if (number < 0) {
            $(this).prev().addClass('negative');
            text = "("+text.replace(/-/g,"")+")";
        } else {
            $(this).prev().removeClass('negative');
        }

        $(this).prev().val(text);
        $(this).prev().removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
input {
    text-align:right;
    width:10em;
    /* box-sizing keeps width fixed when adding padding (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9484932/1652620) */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

.input [type='text'] {
    background-color:yellow;
    padding-right:14px; /* line up with number text */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.input [type='number'] {background-color:orange;}
.hidden {display:none;}
.negative {color:red;}

/* Formatting to add $ sign (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8222528/1652620) */
.input {position: relative;}
.currency_symbol {
 font-size:0.6em;
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    left:5px;
}
.currency_symbol::before {content:"$"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="input">
    <input type="text" value="-" />
    <input type="number" class="hidden" />
</span>
<br/>
<span class="input">
    <input type="text" value="-" />
    <input type="number" class="hidden" />
</span>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00pxe49t/10/)**

Comment: The inputs also disappears when you click on them, if you don't remove the `.focus()` it will always disappear on FF mac

Comment: @Huangism seems to work fine for me in Chrome - i think the idea is to switch viewing text and number. Which browser are you using - maybe it is interpreting number inputs as text

Comment: Updated my comment, FF is having the disappearing act with focus

Comment: This FF Mac issue has me scratching my head so much that I've posted [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27181708/1652620) about it. The code above can't be deployed if I can't get it to function on Firefox. @Huangism, if you have any insight, I'd very much appreciate your input on that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply isolate the `$(this)` inside a variable like so :

```
$('.input [type="number"]').on('blur', function(){
    var number = Math.round($(this).val() * 100) / 100;
    var number = Math.round($(this).val() * 100) / 100;
    var text = number.toFixed().toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var this$ = $(this);
    if (number < 0) {
         this$.prev().addClass('negative');
        text = "("+text.replace(/-/g,"")+")";
    }
[...]
```